# Kill all PHP scripts with a PHP script

Tags: php, server, webserver, client-server

Is there a way to kill all the **PHP** scripts from a PHP script.

I want to make a PHP file named `kill.php` which kills all the running PHP scripts running on my server whenever i open it.

Or maybe restart the server.

Is it possible to do that? Point me in the right direction.

Thanks

Comment: but why? ... what's the purpose? either way... http://php.net/manual/en/function.posix-kill.php

Comment: I know how to do that on terminal, but i was just wondering if i can do it without opening my computer and by just typing a url to that php script @Hallur

Comment: Any specific reason you need that?

Comment: You will find the answer you need if you read the manual... especially the link I gave you. I won't write the whole thing for you.

Comment: Thanks @Hallur  for the link

Comment: @Charlotte my website is a search engine and sometimes i want to stop my crawlers which runs on the same server, to save memory for the client traffic